# SQL Query: can't figure out which clause should i use

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Overview of the problem: I have 2 tables that control events from a `CoinDepositMachine`.

In the first table I have the id of the machine, the operation that occurred and the date of the operation.

In the second table, I have the same id, and the value ($) of the operation.

What I want is the amount between the last `CoinCollectOperation` (`OperationCode = 3`) of each machine.

Something like this:

```
ID    Value    Date
-------------------------
3     $87      08/30/2014
3     $42      09/02/2014 ($42 is the amount btw 09/02 and 08/30)
3     $39      09/05/2014
6     $12      06/30/2014
6     $5       07/05/2014
6     $78      07/15/2014
6     $52      07/22/2014
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data or, better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Can you post the schema of all 3 tables, or better yet, a SQL Fiddle? Not clear on what you want here.

Comment: This screams of poor architecture. Why is part of the operation in one table and the other part of the operation in another table? Seems like you should have a machines table and an operations table.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the [Lag Function] or you may be trying to [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) and group by OperationCode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) I can't be sure from the information you provided